# Method 'get_Info' error when working with identity server and asp identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I was working my way through the basic tutorial of identity server. the tutorial only talks about using sqlite, so I decided to integrate sql server to it.

I got this error

> Method 'get_Info' in type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerOptionsExtension'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer,
>   Version=1.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
>   does not have an implementation.

This command had worked earlier in another project, so the command itself is fine. also, there are other issues with this error but they all relate to mysql and not with mssql which is what I was using.

Answer (score 0):

This is the line where, I ran into errors.

options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));

but, I got rid of it, and there were no build errors. I assumed, this mean, the related Sql frameworks were included.

But, the get_info method is part of the sql server package.

So,

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

added the actual package that contains this definition, even though, it did not show any build errors. Its very silly but I think this could useful for someone else, so putting it here, as Q and A.